# Cannot add Static Lib (C++) as a Reference due to targeting different platforms

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries

I'm experienced w/C# and C, but not with C++.  I need to interface to an API in C / C++, so I'm off to learn C++ with Visual Studio 2015 Pro.

I built a *very* simple example to test the library of classes (as a static library) being used in a console application for testing.

I cannot add my library as a reference because VS 2015 claims that they target different platforms.  However, the properties indicate the *same* platform.

[image: Properties from Project Lib]

[image: Properties from Console App]

What is this error telling me that I don't understand?

[image: Error message after selecting 'ok' in add references]

Comment: How is your solution structured? Do you have the Lib and the App projects in the same solution? Are you using a reference to connect the lib to the app?

Comment: Are you running 2015 R3 (Check Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates)

Comment: Lib + App in the same solution.  Just trying to connect the lib to the app as you indicated.

Comment: Have not updated...

Comment: updating now...

Comment: Updated... no change in results.

Comment: Pretty bummed now...  I'm getting a chronic 'VS Error loading expression evaluator dll'  Now VS is useless until I figure out this problem!

Comment: Windows App Store Support is different

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  To which problem are you referring?  My original problem with libraries or the new problem with the expression evaluator dll?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve your problem? I'm having the same issue. (Question is quite old... but maybe you have the solution).

Comment: It was too long ago for me to remember.  I'll have to think about it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and doing something similar.

I had the same problem and I think what happened was maybe I chose the "static library" project and "executable" project from different submenus in the Visual Studio project creation wizard.

I went back through the project creation wizard and made sure I selected an executable type from the same category as my static library (in my case, "Universal Windows"). That platform setting is shown in parentheses after the Project name and seems to be different than the SDK settings the error seems to refer to.

I was looking for a way to "convert" my project from "Visual Studio 2010" (its original setting somehow) to "Universal Windows" but I haven't found one yet. I tried using Solution Explorer's "Retarget solution" option (in the right click context menu for the solution) but all it did was get me off Visual Studio 2010 and onto something that didn't have a reference at all. So I made a new project and copied the files over into it.